# How to pass an id to a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

I have a has_many :through relationship, and the fallowing scenario:
A user is able to create an `project` and add many `words` to that project. The 'words' will be stored just once in the database, and if they already exist in the join table an association will be created.

What I have so far:

A `project controller`
which is adding the project into the table and redirects to a show page, where is another simple_form_for in where all the words will go.

```
def show
 @word = word.new
end
```

`Project show View`

```
<%= simple_form_for @word do |f|%>
    <%=f.input :name%>
    <%=f.button :submit%>
<%end%>
```

In the `word controller` `create action`
I would like to get the project id and populate the `join table` and the `words` table.

`@project = Project.find(params[:id])`

So how can I get the `project_id` and populate the join table and use `find_or_create_by` populate the `words` table.

(I know that the `project_id` can be found in the URL, also I can print it by using `@project.id`) in the view

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting the question right, you want to create a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between project and word.
so in your Project.rb add

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :words
```

and in your Word.rb add

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

Now for this relationship create a new table projects_words with two fields 'project_id' and 'word_id'

In project controller inside show action

```
@words = Word.new
```

In show page of project add this:-

```
<%= form_for @word,:url => words_path(:project_id => @project.id) do |f|%>
  <%=f.label :name%>
  <%=f.text_field :name%>
  <%=f.button :submit%>
<%end%>
```

Now in the word controller create action do like this:-

```
@word = Word.find_or_create_by_name(params[:word][:name])
@word.projects = Project.where(:id => params[:project_id])
@word.save
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass Project ID in the URL like this,

Projects Controller:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

projects/show.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @word, :url => words_path(:project_id=> @project.id), :method => :post do |f| %>
  <%=f.input :name%>
  <%=f.button :submit%>
<%end%>
```

Sorry if this didn't work, I haven't tested this.